# Saving passwords with options() not saving to global options for future use

Tags: r, rstudio

I need to save two sets of passwords in a script for subsequent api calls and sql database connections. Do I save these in global options or .Rprofile?

Currently, I'm using `options(password = password)`, and calling in the api with `getOption(password)` for the api. For the sql server connection, I need to save the password as an object in the script and call it in the `dbConnect(RMariaDB())` call. Isn't there an anonymous way to save these locally, or even better, to the .Rproj profile?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, as found in [this document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html), the best approach for this is dependent on the uses. In  my case, saving to .Renviron is best.

```
file.edit("~/.Renviron")
```

```
VAR1 = value1
VAR2 = value2
```

```
Sys.getenv("VAR1")
#> [1] "value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open/Creat your `Rproj` file
2. Tune your environment variables:
   Create all variables, data, functions you want to have access each time you run your project
   [image]
3. Close R and save image .RData. It must be located in the same directory than your `.rproj` 
   Close RStudio and when they ask you if you want to save .RData, save it in the same folder you have your .rproj file
   [image]

Next time you open your `Rproj` your environment defined in step 2 will be automatically restored
[image]

Comment: Thanks @LocoGris - could you expand on what you mean by point 2 and 3? What do I save to .RData?

Comment: Hi @LocoGris, thank you, although this doesn't really solve my issue - I want the passwords to remain hidden. I also cannot access the options in a subsequent session using ```load("./options.Rdata")``` after saving the RData file into the project